# String.replaceAll does not apply to any kind of characters

Tags: java, string, replaceall

So what i've got is this simple method which should remove all characters except upper and lowercase letters and numbers from a string.

```
public static String toSimple(String arg) //redurziert einen String auf Buchstaben und ganze Zahlen
{
    String string = arg;
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < string.length())
    {
        if (((int)string.charAt(i) >= 48 && (int)string.charAt(i) <= 57)||((int)string.charAt(i) >= 65 && (int)string.charAt(i) <= 90)||((int)string.charAt(i) >= 97 && (int)string.charAt(i) <= 121))
            i+=1;
        else
        {
            int a = string.length();
            string = string.replaceAll(""+string.charAt(i), "");

            if (!(string.length() < a)) //Just in case
            {
                i+=1;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that in some cases `string.replaceAll` won't change anything though reached and given a character. I checked it in the debugger and couldn't find any apparent errors or exceptions. I didn't check the whole ASCII table, I know that the problem will occur for '$' '?' and '.'.
Any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: Note that char literals can be used instead of "magic numbers" - so `(int)string.charAt(i) >= 48` can be written as `string.charAt(i) >= '0'`, which makes it a lot more obvious what you mean. (The cast to `int` isn't necessary in any case).

Comment: That's a pretty horrible way to remove characters from a String. And it doesn't work. Try the string ",,,+a" - it won't remove the "+". Normally you would build a new String in a StringBuilder but even if you were doing it like this, you'd use `String.substring` twice to get the string before and after the character.

Answer (score 2):

[`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes a regular expression as its first parameter.

`$`, `?` and `.` are special characters in [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead - this actually uses regular expressions internally too, but it escapes the strings correctly.

---

However, given that you're using `String.replaceAll`, you can just use a regular expression to do the whole thing:

```
return arg.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: man, that's much easier ':D thanks

Comment: Or `arg.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", "")`

Comment: @Wiktor indeed. I suggested the explicit ranges because that matches OP's code.